# how to insert text in textarea dynamicaly from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to insert text in textarea on a button click and this text should be added at the place of my cursor not the end of the text

```js
function add1(){
  var msg=$('#msg').val();
  $('#msg').val(msg+"hello");
}
function add2(){
  var msg=$('#msg').val();
  $('#msg').val(msg+"world");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="msg"></textarea>
<button onclick="add1()">hi</button>
<button onclick="add2()">world</button>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question you can't insert the text at the cursor position as there will be no cursor in the textfield while you are clicking a button.

Comment: i want to insert text at a dynamic position in textarea